# Android ProgressBar setProgress() update causes frame drops in Camera Preview

Tags: android, performance, android-handler

I have a layout which consist of a Camera Preview on the top and a progress bar below it.

The progress bar is responsible of updating the progress of a MediaPlayer.
I'm using a Handler to achieve this, the problem is when I start the media player, the progress bar updates causes some frame drops on the camera preview.

I need to maintain the same frame rate which is ~30 fps initially.

Handler code :

```
protected Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // waveprogress is the ProgressBar
            waveProgress.setProgress((mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100) / mMediaPlayer.getDuration());
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                waveProgress.post(runnable);
                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS), 350);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to use Camera.PreviewCallback and just update your progress bar?